# How do I get docpad server running / generating in Cloud 9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide, docpad

When I do the "docpad run" command in the Cloud 9 Terminal it gives me a IP address like:

```
http://127.9.102.129:8080/
```

but nothing is there. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Docpad allows for a .env file to set process.env.STUFF and you can set the port in docpad.coffee (from http://docpad.org/docs/config) but we don't need those tricks to get our docpad running in C9.

Instead we simply setup a "RUN & DEBUG" context for C9 via the RUN & DEBUG tab. The name can be anything. The "File Path:" will be set to be the same as docpad's "main" in it's package.json, which is "./node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server". the "Runtime" can be left as "Default" and we don't need any "Cmd Line Args" either. So your docpad Run settings might look like the following:

```
Name           docpad.coffee
File Path      ./node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server
Runtime        Default
Cmd Line Args
```

[image: RUN & DEBUG settings for docpad in Cloud 9 IDE]

Then just you to the green Run button at the top and click the little drop-down arrow on the right of the button and select the Run context you just setup. In our example above it would be "docpad.coffee". Once you click that, the C9 console will popup from below and begin the docpad run command as usual except before it does, it gives you your C9 url where to test/preview your docpad app!

And that's all it takes, your online with docpad and C9.

8)

Comment: Truthfully I couldn't get any other C9 docpad project online. So if you get it working, great! If not, it's C9's fault...

8(